# what is the regex expression to identify comments (i.e. between /* and */ across multiple lines)

Tags: regex

What is the regex expression to identify comments (i.e. all characters between /* and */ , including these comment markers themselves, and across multiple lines)?

So for example to pickup:

```
/* asdf asdf 
asdf asdfasdfasdfasd
asdfasdf
   */
```

Comment: "including these comment markers themselves" - congratulations, you need to use a context-aware parser instead!

Comment: Personally, I'd use a parser, but here's a link to regex that I believe will work:  http://snipplr.com/view/7129/match-css-and-js-comments/. Link to another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984380/regular-expression-to-remove-css-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:/\*(?:(?:[^*]|\*(?!/))*)\*/)
```

This was originally part of a MySQL parser, designed to strip comments without removing them from strings:

```
("(?:(?:(?:\\.)|[^"\\\r\n])*)"|'(?:(?:(?:\\.)|[^'\\\r\n])*)'|`(?:(?:(?:\\.)|[^`\\\r\n])*)`)|((?:-- .*)|(?:#.*)|(?:/\*(?:(?:[^*]|\*(?!/))*)\*/))
```

That gets replaced with capture group 1 to put the strings back.

Comment: fantastic thank you - I think I'm glad I didn't him persisting trying to work it out myself

Comment: This won't allow `*/` inside the comment

Comment: interestly whilst this worked in an online regex tool, when I try to use it in NotePad++ it doesn't work   :(

Comment: @Patrick - clearly, but I'm pointing out the fallacy in OP's requirements: "including these comment markers themselves" - which means this should be allowed: /* bla bla */ bla */

Comment: sometimes text editors have their own syntax, like requiring the brackets to be backslashed as well

Comment: sorry - I just meant the ones at the extremes, so Patrick's suggestion is fine - however the tool I was going to use it on in windows to do the replacement doesn't seem to work - any ideas for a free Windows regex replacement tool that would respect the regex pattern correctly?

Comment: Textpad requires you to escape the brackets, I'm not sure about Editpad.

Comment: @Greg: "a free Windows regex replacement tool": http://perl.org/get.html You could use `perl -0777 -pe "s{/\*.*?\*/}{}gs" foo.txt` for simple cases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112618/what-is-the-regex-expression-to-identify-comments-i-e-between-and-across/5112847#5112847

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* difficult problem to solve with a regex (since it is very hard to account for all the edge cases). If this is a programming language that you are parsing I would highly suggest that you use a parser built to parse that language.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that simple e.g.:

```
/* multiline comment
   f("end marker inside literal string */");
*/
```

See [How do I use a regular expression to strip C style comments from a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?).