# How to match c-style block comments in Notepad++ with a regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

With the intent to match multiline comments, I found the following regex:

```
  (?:/\*(?:(?:[^*]|\*(?!/))*)\*/)
```

It is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112618/what-is-the-regex-expression-to-identify-comments-i-e-between-and-across). It isn't perfect (it matches comments inside strings), but it works well enough for my purpose. However, it does not work in Notepad++. I tried escaping different things, but with no better results.

Does anyone know how to make this regex work in Notepad++?

Comment: I think the problem is that Notepad++ doesn't apply regexes across multiple lines, which is what you're trying to do according to the linked question. It also doesn't support lookahead expressions. Use a better editor :)

Comment: oh...any suggestions?  :)  Notepad++ was good as it's lightweight and free...

Comment: what exactly do you want do to? see the matches, replace text, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepadd++ uses scintilla's regular expression engine (according to its online help).

[This page](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html) says that "in Scintilla, regular expression searches are made line per line," so unfortunately I think it's hopeless.

-- EDIT --

A little further digging turned up [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/4056271) notepad++ forum post, which offers some hope after all.  Specifically, it says that notepad++'s PythonScript plugin supports multiline regular expressions.

Comment: Just thought I'd add: since this post/question were added to this site, Notepad++ was updated to support these things. In fact, I blieve the regex might just work without anything special.

Answer (score 6):

When the question was asked, the correct answer was that you couldn't do this in Notepad++, because its regex flavor didn't support regexes matching over multiple lines and lookahead (both of which are essential in the given regex).

However, Notepad++ has a much more powerful regex engine these days - since version 6.0 it supports full pcre regexes. This means your regex as given in the question just works. As such, I believe the correct answer would now just be "open the search menu, input your regex, choose regex for search mode and click search".

Comment: I highly recommend [EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) if you need to do this sort of thing a lot. The regular expression support is way better than any other editor I have ever used.