# remove fake comments from json file

Tags: php, regex

since json dosn't support comments I need my own function to clean my comments
My comments are css style, like this

```
/*comment*/
```

i tryed the following

```
    $json = preg_replace("/(\/\*.?\*\/)/", "", $json);
```

but no luck.
thank's

Comment: Your `.?` placeholders just matches one arbitrary character, or no character.

Comment: Thats a pretty tall order for regex since you'll need to handle cases like `"this is a string /*this is not a comment*/"` where things between `/*` and `*/` shouldn't be removed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove CSS comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984380/regular-expression-to-remove-css-comments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to strip comments and multi-line comments and empty lines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/643113)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$json = preg_replace('!/\*.*?\*/!s', '', $json); // remove comments
$json = preg_replace('/\n\s*\n/', "\n", $json); // remove empty lines that can create errors
```

This will erase comments, multi line comments and empty lines

**EDIT:** as some of the guys were saying in the comments, you can use:

```
 $json = preg_replace('/\s*(?!<\")\/\*[^\*]+\*\/(?!\")\s*/', '', $json);
```

To remove only comments that are not found within strings.

Comment: @YotamOmer: comments embedded in strings would be stripped out with this method.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo preg_replace("#/\*.*?\*/#s", "", $json);
```

Notable changes:

- I used `#` as the pattern delimiter. By doing this, I don't need to
  escape forward slashes, making the regex prettier to read.
- I added the `s` flag, which makes the **`.`** also match new line characters.

Beware, this will destroy comments inside a json string. An example json object that will get clobbered

```
{"codeSample": " /*******THIS WILL GET STRIPPED OUT******/"}
```

Comment: And can corrupt too `{"a":"b/*c","d":"e"/*f*/}` ---> `{"a":"b}`

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "some text /*comment goes here*/ some text again /*some comment again*/";
$string = preg_replace( '/\s*(?!<\")\/\*[^\*]+\*\/(?!\")\s*/' , '' , $string );
echo $string; // some textsome text again
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete php code to remove both single and multi-line comments.

```
$json = preg_replace('!/\*.*?\*/!s', '', $json); //Strip multi-line comments: '/* comment */'
$json = preg_replace('!//.*!', '', $json);       //Strip single-line comments: '// comment'
$json = preg_replace('/\n\s*\n/', "\n", $json);  //Remove empty-lines (as clean up for above)
```

Here a site you can test the code: https://www.phpliveregex.com

[To test the first code line fill in like this picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSeYz.png)