# sed command to strip CSS comments not working

Tags: css, bash, sed

I'm trying to strip comments from a CSS file using `sed`. I'm using macOS, and [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.0/normalize.css) as a test file.

So far, I have this:

```
sed -E 's,\/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*\/,,g' < normalize.css > normalize.min.css
```

This does not work whatsoever; all the comments remain in the resulting `normalize.min.css` file.

I'm taking the regex from the [CSS comments spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html#scanner).

I've also tried it without substitute:

```
sed -E '/\/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*\//d' < normalize.css > normalize.min.css
```

With no luck.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The whole reason to use an alternate delimiter like `,` is so that you don't need to escape the forward slashes. `s,/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/,,g`. That said, the original appears to work fine for a simple input like `/* foo */`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Yeah I was messing around a lot, please excuse the delimiters. My testfile was normalize.css, so I'll update the question with that.

Comment: it'd help to create a small sample (say 5-10 lines) and show which lines to delete... single line comments? multiline comments? sed by default works only one line at a time (newline is default separator)... may be `sed '\#^/\*#,\#\*/$#d'` is the one you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is [doable with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3984380/187808). However, if you use a line-oriented tool, then it becomes unnecessarily difficult to do. This task is yelling at me, like **accidental complexity!**

I wouldn't push this any further. Here is an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-css-comments) for this so you can add it to your builds. Here is an online [css minifier](https://www.freeformatter.com/css-minifier.html) so you can use it ad-hoc.

I don't know what kind of site you're building. However, a css preprocessor might simplify your work anyway. Here is a [good overview](https://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus).

Comment: Hi Tamas, thanks for the rely. I'm aware of css minifiers and pre-processors, and use them frequently. I was looking for a (hopefully) simple shell-based solution for a small use-case where I'd like to remove as many dependencies as possible.

Comment: I'd go with php cli or a perl one-liner then. Since `sed` is line oriented, this is waaay more difficult than it should be.

Comment: gotcha. I accept the answer "this is not a good idea". thanks!