# Regular Expression to find non commented java lines

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a pattern for negative look behind regEx to not to match certain lines of code in my java file.
I could match the phrase with this "`(?<=//).*getMessage.*`"
Above expression matches Line #1 in below code,

```
// Systme.out.println (obj1.getMessage());  //line1
/* Systme.out.println (obj.getMessage());*/ //line2    
/* public void test() {                     //line3 
   Systme.out.println (obj2.getMessage());  //line4
   }                                        //line5
*/ 
public void test() {                       
      Systme.out.println (obj5.getMessage()); //line 6
 }
```

But, when i tried negate this using "`(?<!//).*getMessage.*`", It still matches all the Line #1,#2 and #4 as well.

Actually my requirement is to match the `getMessage` call at line #6 and ignore other places where `getMessage` is called inside comments.

It would be great if someone can assist me in finding the right expression.

PS: I can't access java files... I just have to pass the RegEx to a form and select all the java files checkbox.

Comment: You'd probably need to use two expressions, especially for finding comments spanning multiple lines, i.e. between `/*` and `*/`. Note that applying a regular expression to a non-regular domain (such as almost every language is) will always be an approximation only.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using the following regex to delete all the comments and then use a simple regex to find all `getMessage()` calls.

REGEX: <s>~/(?:/.*?$|*.*?*/)~</s>

```
String regex = "(?ms)/(?:/.*?$|\*.*?\*/)"
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tN8oQ8/4)**

Please note the `s` flag, making the `.` match newline characters, too. You can use a character with a complemented group instead of the `.` So that would be something like `[\w\W]` instead of the second `.`

Comment: @Thomas I tried to make a regex that would catch if comment was in quotes and **[this](http://regex101.com/r/tN8oQ8/5)** what I got so far. Unfortunately, this means you can't have quotes in a comment at all. So it's far from perfect. I think I need a negative lookbehind, but I haven't fully grasped the syntax for it

Comment: @skamazin actually a programming language is a non-regular problem domain and as such regular epxressions have their limitations. To be absolutely sure you'd need to use a more appropriate representation, e.g. an AST.

Comment: This regex would delete a wanted `getMessage()` in this scenario: http://regex101.com/r/qP4lK8/1 (edge case I agree, but my answer below handles is correctly)

Comment: @funkwurm There's bound to be many edge cases I didn't account for. If OP wants to be 100% sure that there are no errors, he should use some predefined parser instead of a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

What if there's a string that contains `getMessage`? ;)

This is what I would do and then extract every find of group 2:

```
(['"])(?:(?!\1|\\).|\\.)*\1|\/\/[^\n]*(?:\n|$)|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*(?!\/))*\*\/|(getMessage\(\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oedqjZVmLhBtqPaa)

(This is an adaptation of my more general approach I further explain and posted about here: [Regex for comments in strings, strings in comments, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402109/regex-for-comments-in-strings-strings-in-comments-etc))

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using [the `String` literal pattern from skamazin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25426000), you can compile it with `Pattern` modifiers as well:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("/(?:/.*?$|\*.*?\*/)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

**Read more:**

- [Constant Field Values - java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.regex.Pattern.CANON_EQ)