# Syntax Highlighting in FlowDocumentControl for RScript

Tags: c#, regex, flowdocument, rscript

We have use the following Regex function to highlight the string and numeric

**String Regex function**

```
public string StringRegEx
{
    get { return @"@?""""|@?"".*?(?!\\).""|''|'.*?(?!\\).'"; }
}
```

**Numeric Regex function**

```
public string NumberRegEX
{
    get { return @"[0-9].*?(?=:[0-9]*)?"; }
}
```

while using this regex function we have face some issues for highlighting string contains numeric

```
p1 = 1
p2 = 0.2
```

[image]

In this example, 1 and 2 in p1 and p2 also highlighted. How to skip the number highlighted along with the string?

Comment: Your string regex contains `.` which matches all.You can use `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: p1 and p2 are not matched by the first regex (which is used to match string literal - it is bugged, though). It is only matched by the second regex. Your regex are very poor, btw.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general approach on how to properly catch things when dealing with a programming language snippet, **[take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402109/regex-for-comments-in-strings-strings-in-comments-etc)**.

Your problem might not be "comments in strings, strings in comments" but it is similar, namely "letters in a string that started with a number, numbers in a string that started with a letter" so you'll need a similar approach with pipe-separated regexes for the different matches you wanna have.

A more thorough explanation of this design-pattern is given **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between/23589204#23589204)**.