# regular expression for tag in Jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to find a regular expression for replace the commentaires in my js files. What i want is transform all line like this :

```
 //it's a commentaire
```

into this

```
 /* it's a commentaire */
```

Because i try to optimize my files, and there are issues i think it's come from this. I use php function file_get_content, and it create a string in one line, so all the string become a commentaire causse of the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\/\/([^\n]*)
```

You can try this.Replace by `/* $1 */`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/9

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below  regex to match the strings which starts with `//` upto the end of the line. In multiline mode, dot would match any character but not of newline character. So you could use `.*` to match all the following characters and putting the brackets around `(.*)` would turn the matches into [captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
\/\/(.*)
```

Replace the matched strings by `/* $1 */`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aB2vZ7/1)

```
> var s = "foo //it's a commentaire".replace(/\/\/(.*)/g, "/* $1 */")
undefined
> console.log(s)
foo /* it's a commentaire */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna be on the safe side, you wanna account for this stuff:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var var1 = prompt('Which character does line-escapes?', '//');
</script>
```

Which isn't a comment because it's inside of a string. I made a post about just this over **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402109/regex-for-comments-in-strings-strings-in-comments-etc)**. So what you wanna do is use the regex from that answer and inspect the content to see if you're dealing with a line-comment. Easiest way to do that is put the one you want in a capture group:

```
(\/\/([^\n]*)(?:\n|$))|(['"])(?:(?!\3|\\).|\\.)*\3|\/(?![*/])(?:[^\\/]|\\.)+\/[igm]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*(?!\/))*\*\/
```

Now, if capture group 1 is not empty, replace it with `/*$2*/`. Otherwise, don't do anything (or replace it with the entire match, effectively not changing anything.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JHe6yNDCatyoUe43)