# Regular expression for comments

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a lot of code and would like to find and replace some text in it. I want to replace all matches, but excluding those that are in comments. Suppose I want to find and replace string "text" in my code.  Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("text"); // must be replaced 
// some text    /* does not need to be replaced because this string begins from  "//"  */
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it with regular expressions. Could someone help me?

Comment: what would the output in second line?

Comment: the second line does not be found. Regex i wanna get hasn't to match "text" in second line

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for comments in strings, strings in comments, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402109/regex-for-comments-in-strings-strings-in-comments-etc)

Comment: @funkwurm: Not dup. This searching for some text outside comment, not extracting the parts. Your post is useful if it is possible to supply a replacement function, though.

Comment: So the thing is that you wanna search for both the comment and the text, and only handling the capture-group that contains the text. That way text inside the comment gets captured in a capture-group that you leave alone. This is more thoroughly explained **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between/23589204#23589204)**. But if you expect line-comment delimiters inside strings, you should _also_ capture those to prevent them from getting captured as a comment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Going strictly by the requirement *"find `text` unless surrounded by `//` and `\n`"*, this would be the regex to use and only handle capture group 1. But note (like I said in the comment) that comment-delimiters inside string aren't accounted for, as the 3rd line in the [debuggex demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bkcL4zkel4SPeIUL) shows. nhahtdh is correct in saying that a replace callback function would be the way to go here, you can then capture any string and further investigate it in the callback.

```
\/\/[^\n]*(?:\n|$)|(text)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bkcL4zkel4SPeIUL)

Answer (score -1):

```
^[^\/]+(\/\/.*)\n
```

I think this should suit your needs

Comment: You are missing the point. OP want to replace `text`, not the line with comment.