# Using RegEx in Java, how do I capture groups delimited by double pipes excluding those enclosed by double quotes?

Tags: java, regex

Example:

```
abc | efg || $something("arg 1", "arg 2||(a|b)") || 123
```

or without whitespace

```
abc|efg||$something("arg 1", "arg 2||(a|b)")||123
```

What RegEx pattern is needed so that I can get the following groups:

```
abc | efg
$something("arg 1", "arg 2||(a|b)")
123
```

Total of 3 groups.

Another example:

```
"abc || efg" || 123
```

Should give me 2 groups

```
"abc || efg"
123
```

Basically it cuts or splits the string by double pipes but excluding double pipes within double quotes.

My failed attempts are the following:

.+?(?=\|\|)|.*

\".+?\"|.+?(?=\|\|)|.*

Comment: By what do you wanna cut the string into pieces?

Comment: The approach you wanna use is described here: **[Comments in strings, string in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402109/regex-for-comments-in-strings-strings-in-comments-etc)**. Only you work with **_OR_-operator in strings, string between _OR_-operators**. But the general idea is the same.

Comment: Please stick with one splitting string. Do you want to split on un-quoted " || " or on un-quoted "||"? Each of your examples is different in that regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I would do, regex-wise:

```
(?:^|\|\|)(?:(?!\|\|)(?!").|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*")*
```

Regex101 demo **[here](https://regex101.com/r/vA1nO8/4)**. You can see the matches to the right, I put them in capture groups to omit the `||`, you can get them with `m.group(1)` in Java. Java is not my forte but it should be something like this:

```
String s ="abc | efg || $something(\"arg 1\", \"arg 2||(a|b)\") || 123";   
String patternStr="(?:^|\\|\\|)(?:(?!\\|\\|)(?!\").|\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Edit:** Realized looking back that you probably wanna accept `"$something("arg with \" in it", "arg 2||(a|b)"` so updated the regex to do that.

**Added:** Combining with Bohemian's solution, you could split on this if that's easier:

```
\|\|(?=(?:(?:(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eN9cP8/1)** or in Java:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\|\\|(?=(?:(?:(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
```

Comment: @supertonsky I just changed my answer slightly, after you accepted it. It now handles escaped quotes like `"arg1 \" || something"` as 1 string and doesn't cut it off at the `||`. Would've been a nasty bug that only shows it self in very specific cases.

Comment: Why there's a need for nested non-capturing groups? Tried removing one of it and it seems to be still working. (?:^|\|\|)((?:"(?:[^"]|\")*"|(?:(?!\|\|).))*)

Comment: Ah, you're right, the one you deleted was unnecessary, as well the one around `(?!\\|\\|).`. It's a result of my regex dev-process :) I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Just simply awesome. Any links on how to develop that thought process on how to do regex "dev-process"?

Comment: A good starting point would be **[this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between/23589204#23589204)**. I usually use mainly [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/) as it gives a visual "path". Unfortunately it has some bugs in the actual regex-handling (for this question specifically, how to handle escaped OR-operators: `\|`) so then I use the more reliable but less visually pleasing [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Oh, [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is also a really good tutorial and reference. More generic about regular expressions if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: It fails on this scenario: env("test") || env("another")

Comment: Updated the answer once more, should now work (regex101 demo updated as well)

Answer (score 1):

```
\|\|(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/47

Comment: In Java the regex is a string an as such the `"` would have to be escaped as well. But clever way to accept multiple strings after the matched `||`.

Comment: @funkwurm dont have much idea about java :(

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to not use split but instead go through multiple matches, you can use
`(?<=\ \|\|\ |^)([^\"]+?(?:\"[^\"]*\")?)+?(?=\ \|\|\ |$)`
Explanation:

1. Look-behind: " || " or start of line?
2. Some non-quote text, as little as possible
3. Optionally, a quote-enclosed block of non-quotes
4. 2.-3. repeated at least once
5. Look-ahead: " || " or end of line?

The matches will precisely be the results of a split by " || " with quoted || ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Split on double pipes, but only those followed by an *even* number of quotes:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\|\\|(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this short regex** `\|\|(?!\([^\)]+\))`  it may work.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA1mX9/1)

Comment: Breaks if there are more strings with `||` after each other: https://regex101.com/r/aA1mX9/2